# how to set backarrow in place of hamburger icon for only 1 single fragment?

Tags: android

I have replaced all the hamburger icons from all the fragments with the help of the code given below in MainActivity.

```
 toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
 toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.leftarrow);
```

Now I want that backarrow should be there in only one fragment and rest of the fragments should be having hamburger icon.The fragment in which I want the back arrow is the one which is redirected from another fragment on onclick of some data in cardview.I need to set backarrow in toolbar therre in placeof hamburger icon to navigate back to previous fragment containing cardview. I am unable to solve it.

Comment: You always have the option of passing a Bundle with data to the newly created fragment mentioning who called it. Then using getArgument() in the fragment will know who called it and change the icon in the onCreateView in the fragment you need the backarrow. Hope it helps !

Comment: Set Toolbar in your MainActivity, now when you load that fragment, set navigationIcon in toolbar as back icon and when you come back from that fragment you can replace that icon with hamburger again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Like this

Use Harmburger Icon in Main Activity, replace harmburger icon with back arrow when `fragment` is called in `onCreateView` Method. Since i've Data Binding Concepts, so i taking the reference of activity binding., if you not using Data binding concepts., take the Activity Reference and initiate the `ActionBarToggle` and replace the icons

```
ActivityDashboardBinding activityDashboardBinding = DashboardActivity.getActivityDashboardBinding();

ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(),
activityDashboardBinding.drawerLayout, activityDashboardBinding.toolbar,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back);
```

Note : once you replacing the Harmburger icon with back_arrow in one `fragment`, you need handle this in all `fragment` or else write a common static method in main activity., call the method from every `fragment`.

Comment: I have already replaced the icon with the backarrow icon which is reflecting in all the fragments. Problem is how to allow it's visibility in one fragment only and manage other fragment's visibility and show hamburger icon in every other fragment.

Comment: I am able to replace it in mainactivity only and not in any other fragment. So I am unable to replace from fragments. I am also not using onbindview.

Comment: yes ! that's why i said to create static method in activity and call it all all fragments, just pass the fragment name and handle the icons and actions based on fragment name

Comment: @YeshaShah Or else use custom Tool bar, replace the icon image alone when every fragment is called

Comment: @YeshaShah, i replaced the icon in fragment oncreateview only

Answer (score 0):

Try creating two separate navbar's on with hamburger and one with back icon. And use it.

Comment: I cannot use two seperate navbar's. I have to handle all by using one single default toolbar only. Help me in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the hamburger icon in the main activity and change it in the onCreateView in the fragment you want...

Comment: I have used the default toolbar. So it is giving me the default hamburger icon, so I dont need to put anywhere. I have replaced it with backarrow which I want. Now I am stuck that how to change visibility per fragments. I only need backarrow in the fragment which is opening on the click of the cardview in other fragment